# react-hook-form keep validating field after unregister

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm having some issues with react-hook-form where after unregistering a field and keeping its current value, my form won't submit since all fields are validated when attempting to submit it.

My simplified user case is that my form has two field *firstname* and *lastname* with a buttom that will unregister/register lastname and another to submit the form. Please check the following [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-unregister-v6-forked-omllu?file=/src/index.js).

**To reproduce** the issue, click 'unregister lastName' than 'submit'.

**Current result:** Even thought lastName was unregistered, form isn't submitted since lastName has invalid values (was registered previously with required: true).

**Expected resut:** Form should be submited with: *{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }*

My project has the following packages/versions: react (~16.13.1), react-dom (~16.13.1), react-hook-form (^7.2.2), react-scripts (~3.4.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with v7 you need to set

```
shouldUnregister: true //<== NEW
```

```
  const { register, unregister, handleSubmit, formState, getValues } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "Random",
      lastName: "Name"
    },
    shouldUnregister: true
  });
```

See documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform

Comment: This won't work until this PR is accepted. Since unregistering and keeping its values will result in a validation of those fields when attempting to submitting the form.

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/pull/4785

Comment: PR integrated into v7.5.0