# react-hook-form validation triggers even if field has been unregistered

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup, dynamicform

I have a dynamic form, that I can add/remove fields to it.
I use `react-hook-form` and also `yup` to handle form **validation**. 
When a field is removed dynamically, I also `unregister` it using react-hook-form `unregister(name)` method.
It seems to be working fine, the `values` returned by `getValues` do not include those fields that have been unregistered.
The problem is that **`yup` still tries to validate those fields that are required in the resolver-schema even if they are not registered**, so the form will not be submited after submit button has been clicked.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301695/react-hook-form-keep-validating-field-after-unregister), but unfortunately that didn't work for me.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.